# Why is this function code not working?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn C++, and my functions right now. This code is supposed to convert feet to meters. Here is some code I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void instructions(void);
double feetToMeters(double);
int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    instructions();
    feetToMeters(double);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void instructions(void)
{
    cout << "enter a number of feet to convert to meters: ";
    return;
}

double feetToMeters(double feet)
{
    cin >> feet;
    double meters = feet * 3.28084;
    cout << "That is " << meters << " meters";
    return meters;
}
```

and I get **"expected primary-expression before 'double'**". How can I get it to run correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must pass some parameter  instead of 'double' to feetToMeters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void instructions(void);
double feetToMeters(double);
int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    instructions();
    // get the feet value
    cin >> feet;

    // pass the parameter
    feetToMeters(feet);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void instructions(void)
{
    cout << "enter a number of feet to convert to meters: ";
    return;
}

double feetToMeters(double feet)
{
    double meters = feet * 3.28084;
    cout << "That is " << meters << " meters";
    return meters;
}
```

or define `feetToMeters` Function Without any parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void instructions(void);
double feetToMeters(void);
int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    instructions();


    // call function without parameter
    feetToMeters();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void instructions(void)
{
    cout << "enter a number of feet to convert to meters: ";
    return;
}

double feetToMeters(void)
{
    double feet;
    cin >> feet;
    double meters = feet * 3.28084;
    cout << "That is " << meters << " meters";
    return meters;
}
```

Comment: now I'm getting "feet was not declared in this scope" after cin

Comment: sorry i forgot to define feet

Answer (score 4):

The technical answer to the question "Why is this function code not working?" is that your line of code

```
feetToMeters(double);
```

is trying to call a function (`feetToMeters`) with the argument `double`. However, `double` is not a value in C++. It is a reserved word, standing for a type. If you want the function to do a computation, you have to pass it a legal value.

Your code needs to be reorganized a bit. You seem to want to write a function to do the conversion based on an argument you send it, but inside the function, you read the value to be converted from `cin`. You can't have it both ways. The correct approach is to do the reading in `main`, and then pass the value you read over to the function. Then `main` becomes:

```
int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[]) {
    double feet;
    instructions();
    cin >> feet;
    feetToMeters(feet);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Next, remove the line that reads in `feet` from inside your `feetToMeters` function (because it is now in `main`), leaving you with:

```
double feetToMeters(double feet) {
    double meters = feet * 3.28084;
    cout << "That is " << meters << " meters";
    return meters;
}
```

because you've already read it before.

As an aside, I would also put the output line (`cout << ...`) inside of `main` also. That way the function just does the conversion, and `main` handles all the user interaction (input and output).